# How to manage old sandboxes (and clean them up after jobs are no longer running)?

Tags: mesos, marathon

iam new to mesos/marathon, I have a cluster of 5 mesos slaves with one master.
The jobs are placed into mesos slaves, the space in /var/lib/mesos/slaves/../executors start increasing when the task fails and tries to deploy it again and again.

```
backend_gig.42c25d62-2f07-11e7-9b48-025317f685e8             
backend_kw-subscribe.d8bbfff0-2f09-11e7-9b48-025317f685e8
backend_gig.5fb8ab00-2f01-11e7-9b48-025317f685e8             
backend_kw-subscribe.d9d9c645-2f01-11e7-9b48-025317f685e8
backend_gigya.7218ec06-2f04-11e7-9b48-025317f685e8           
backend_kw-subscribe.f7c1bb09-2f05-11e7-9b48-025317f685e8
backend_gigya.97960c51-2f03-11e7-9b48-025317f685e8           
backend_kw-subscribe.fc36ac17-2f06-11e7-9b48-025317f685e8
backend_gig.9e4a9ab7-2f09-11e7-9b48-025317f685e8             
backend_charging-mock.3fcf883a-2e56-11e7-8876-025317f685e8
backend_gig.ac4c9a67-2f06-11e7-9b48-025317f685e8
```

How do I remove the directories of the jobs which are not running/failed/older jobs on mesos slaves?
Would that be controlled by mesos/marathon?
I should set up a cron or some script to remove the directories.
Please suggest as the directories eat up much disk space and slaves go down and unable to start any tasks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mesos has it's own system to handle old sandboxes clean up.

From [documentation](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/sandbox/#sandbox_lifecycle):

> Sandbox files are scheduled for garbage collection when:
>
> - An executor is removed or terminated.
> - A framework is removed.
> - An executor is recovered unsuccessfully during agent recovery.
>
> **NOTE**: During agent recovery, all of the executor’s runs, except for the latest run, are scheduled for garbage collection as well.
>
> Garbage collection is scheduled based on the `--gc_delay` agent flag. By default, this is one week since the sandbox was last modified. After the delay, the files are deleted.
>
> [`--gc_disk_headroom=VALUE`](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/configuration/#gc_disk_headroom) adjust disk headroom used to calculate maximum executor directory age. Age is calculated by: `gc_delay * max(0.0, (1.0 - gc_disk_headroom - disk usage))` every `--disk_watch_interval` duration. `gc_disk_headroom` must be a value between 0.0 and 1.0 (default: 0.1)

Comment: thanks @janisz that worked for me, i set only the gc_delay . would that suffice or "gc_disk_headroom" should also be set, Iam confused on using this parameter, could you explain

Comment: GC disk headroom applies only when disk is fully. If you have plenty of free space probably gc_delay will only count. From my experience its all about experimenting how fast executor sandboxes grows and if disk usage grows drastically then you should either reduce gc_delay or increase gc disk headroom